# In stackoverflow how come users with top reputation have just answered! they don't face problems and ask questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don’t high rep users ask questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13611/why-dont-high-rep-users-ask-questions)

Questions says it all

Comment: Not really. The question is confusing and doesn't provide context.

Comment: I've seen this asked before... just can't find it though... could be deleted. Aha... found it! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13611/why-dont-high-rep-users-ask-questions

Comment: Hmm, maybe there's a correlation between being a good programmer and (no longer) having to ask questions, you think?

Answer (score -3):

Most of StackOverflow is canned answers, and most high reputation users have learned this.

Very few times are there questions that require understanding the situation. We just have to know what you are trying to do.

For instance, clicking a link via Javascript doesn't really require much understanding.

Thats the cool part about programming. There is really only a few ways to do stuff. Which makes it easy to provide answers.

Comment: I disagree on "There is really only a few ways to do stuff" in programming.

Comment: @Vishal: I think his point is that *programming* is essentially *very* simple. The complexity comes from *programmers*.

Comment: -1 on "canned answers".