# Why does the same user have different names in their posts?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do old usernames stick to CW posts by design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240308/476681) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/367303/476681) are from the same user. Why are the answers showing a different user name?

The first answer shows "Martin York", and the second answer shows "Loki Astari".

Comment: Possibly down to the Comminity Wiki tag. I recall that the history shows the name of the user when the question was asked or made Community Wiki rather than the current name...although I'll need to check for sources.

Comment: Good catch Bobby

Comment: [IT WAS BROCK! IT WAS BROCK!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/148310/brock-adams)

Comment: @BrockAdams: Ohh... [IT WAS TOMBULL! IT WAS TOMBULL!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155320/tombull89)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go, took a while for me to find something. The actualy question I was after was a screenshot showing an Adam Davis/Pollyanna CWiki'd question, but as the question below has an answer from Jeff it's probably better.

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design/47522#47522) this is actually [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Granted, this is from April 2010 but I don't think this has changed.

EDIT: Scratch that. The answer from Popular Demand shows the [edit history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2915+wiki%3A1) I was after. See, some answers show "Adam Davis" and some show "Pollyanna". Don't know if this is still [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) though.

Answer (score 9):

This <strike>might be a bug with</strike> is a feature of community-wiki posts.
Consider:

1. There are [currently no users named "Martin York"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=martin+york).
2. According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13611/148310),  [user 14065](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14065) was called "Martin York", circa August 2009:

   [image: Martin York, name history]
3. Now [user 14065](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14065) is called "Loki Astari".

**So,** I'd guess that user 14065 changed his name<sup>1</sup> sometime in the last 2 years (that CW answer was started Oct 27 '08), and that the community-wiki page has <strike>either a display bug or</strike> a nostalgic bent. ;)

See ["Do old usernames stick to CW posts by design?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47474/148310).

<sup>1</sup> My condolences if poor Mr. York was eaten by this Loki (a name synonymous with trouble) and only exists as a host for Mr. Astari.  (^_^)

Comment: That's not a bug, afaik, it's by design. Because CW posts do not belong to one user directly, the name changes are not reflected.

Comment: @Bobby, Yes you are right.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47474.

Comment: +1 for *My condolences if poor Mr. York was eaten by this Loki and only exists as a host for Mr. Astari*

Comment: No trouble here :-)