# Homework Puppies, Help Vampires, and the Über-Selfless Ones

Tags: discussion, homework

I'm beginning to understand why homework questions are annoying.  And I also the see need to grab a stake and aim it a few posts. But then we have those who are helpful, but ask very little.

So my questions:

- are stats *publicly* available to see how many users post **just 1 or 2 questions** ?
- ditto stats on number of users with **reps** of (say) **just 1 to 10** ? ( The Leagues area ? )
- and are there any users with high rep (say > 2K ) who have *never* asked a question ?

(To avoid a likely well-deserved down-voting barrage, I won't suggest a badge for that :-P )

Comment: You can get all those numbers at http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh sooo cool ... @Yannis & psubsee2003 I was about to ask you to post as answers so I could upvote ... until I saw your rep's :))... ahhhh, I wonder if there is a Duck (or a pony) in the lobby of StackExchange Anonymous ...

Comment: -1 for use of "Uber"

Comment: and -1 because there are no German Umlauts LOL

Comment: With regards to your 3rd point: yes. User [Mark Byers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers), for instance, has a rep of ~270k and has 0 questions.

Comment: @arshajii astounding.  Did you glean that via data.se ?

Comment: @HowardPautz Nope, I just went down the top users list.

Comment: Who says one or two questions makes someone a vampire or puppy? What about three? (Like me, and I almost didn't post one of them, because for high-rep users w/ attitudes they're just downvote targets.) Meh.

Comment: @DaveNewton The homework and help ones seem to have low rep or low visits, but the converse is not necessarily true - didn't mean to imply that, sorry if it came so across.

Comment: I have 87K on SO and [one question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154742/how-do-i-get-date-time-information-from-a-timestamp-column). I don't think you can draw too many conclusions from outlier stats.

Comment: Almost -1 for the 3rd point. No-one knows everything. The only issue is whether you know how / where to find information about it (or whether you need to ask on SO). Having asked an SO question or 2 doesn't mean much. Even [the higest-rep best-known user on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) asked 29 questions. Then there's also self-answered questions, i.e. things you know, but just want to share.

Comment: Related: [Why don't high rep users ask questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13611) (Of course, the stats are four years out of date.)

Comment: @ukasz-lech oops I stand corrected, there is an Umlaut here :)) BTW, {put on grammar hat} "Homework questions annoy" and "homework questions are annoying," though logically similar, are different.  "Fire burns" vs "the fires are burning" - there, the difference is clearer than in your edit, of course. Anyhow, enough picking nits ... back to topic: RE Stats. Even as reflected in outlier stats, it's wonderful that folks like Aaron B. and Mark B. are here. On the other hand, how frequently do people make one post and never come back (discounting spammers) - can we see that in the data ?

Comment: @Howard I am trying to grasp why this data is important. I'm sure you can find users that make one post and then leave, but what are you going to do with that information? There are plenty of sites I've only ever interacted with once. Maybe the person lost their job the next day, changed careers, got hit by a bus, became a monk, etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand monks compute too :))  One aspect is the phenomenon of one-or-two posts by new users truly needing help with homework. (Yes, I've read all links on right panel.) I'm wondering about those one-hitters but exclude spammers and people just being lazy (aka help vampires). (The extreme opposite are folks like yourself.)  I wonder if the new posters refrain intentionally or unintentionally from learning SOP ("show effort") due to desperation of being stuck on a problem with nowhere to turn but here. They "speed post" and THEN read the rules. Wrong of course, but it seems to happen.