# Jon Skeet sometimes goes by the alias "Tony the Pony" - but why the reference to ponies?

Tags: discussion, fun, sock-puppets

I finally understood why Jon Skeet did a talk with a sock puppet. Now I read that a "sock puppet" is a term used for a fake user account set up to reinforce somebody's legitimate account...

... but why refer to ponies? Is there a stack overflow reference to ponies that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you mean that [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/67063/tony-the-pony) is Jon Skeet's sock puppet? How did you find that out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ponies are explained here:

[The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19479#19479)

In fact, go ahead and read all those answers and many of the "jokes" will be explained.

Answer (score 20):

The reason for doing a talk with a sock puppet pony was simply because I was [asked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/what-will-jon-skeet-present-in-stackoverflow-devdays-in-london-cambridge/8639#8639) (link requires 10k rep). Obviously it was TheTXI who insisted it should be a pony.

Comment: And, of course, +1 for getting in the "one-trick pony" line.  I didn't know whether to laugh or groan, which resulted in something remarkably close to a pony's whinny...

Comment: @MonicaCellio In my opinion, that question shouldn't be deleted; closure is good enough. Not sure why it was necessary to remove it.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog beats me; before my time.  I'm just here because of a suggested edit.

Comment: @Sonic just flag it asking to undelete and explain why.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot so I can read it in the next few years?